# What does my Processing error, "Debugger halted" mean?

Tags: java, processing

I'm watching The Coding Train's Processing Tutorials. In 5.4, he makes this line of code that is supposed to have an ellipse then move when clicked, but stop when clicked again. But for me it just says `Debugger Halted`. Here is my code:

```
float x = 100;
boolean going = false;

void setup() {
  size(400, 300);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(x, 150, 24, 24);
  if (going) {
    x = x + 2;
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  going = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you're running in debug mode with a break point set.

You probably want to disable debug mode by clicking the butterfly button in the upper-right corner, or you want to find the break point and remove it by clicking the line number with a diamond icon.